# React, webpack-dev-server - Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I am using the webpack-dev-server for developing a bigger project and so far everything works except the connection with the React Developer Tools.

Over the last days i read a lot of threads about the issue and figured out the webpack-dev-server uses an iframe, which is not support by the React Developer Tool (at the moment).

Since i cannot use the webpack-dev-server and the React Developer Tools i tried to run the index.html directly. The index.html now throws the following error:

> Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
> bundle.js:1115:16

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>MetVis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

App.jsx

```
const router = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Main} />
            <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/location" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/comparison" component={Comparison} />
            <Route path="/sensors" component={Sensors} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);


ReactDOM.render(router , document.getElementById('container'));
```